# Cannot get records with datetime less than system date

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to check if a list of records have a `datetime` less than the system `datetime`, these records must have also the field `status` equal as `1` or `2`. What I did is the following:

```
SELECT SUM(m2.datetime < NOW() AND m2.status IN (1, 2)) < 0 AS result 
FROM `match` m2 WHERE m2.round_id = @round_id GROUP BY m2.round_id
```

this query doesn't work in the following scenario:

```
id | datetime              | status |
 1    2018-11-30 18:00:00      5
 2    2018-12-09 13:30:00      5
 3    2018-12-15 14:00:00      5
 4    2018-12-21 13:30:00      5
 5    2019-01-08 17:45:00      1
```

as you can see in the list of records showed above, I have 4 records with a status `5`, and all of these records have a date less than the current system `datetime`. Now, I have another record with the status equal to `1` which have a datetime less than the current, so the result of the query should be `true`, 'cause there is a record that have a `status` equal to `1` and also have a `datetime` less than the system `datetime`. Why the query return false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the count, remove the `< 0`.

```
SELECT round_id, SUM(m2.datetime < NOW() AND m2.status IN (1, 2))AS result 
FROM `match` m2
WHERE m2.round_id = @round_id
GROUP BY m2.round_id
```

Or better yet, move the condition to the `where` clause:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS result 
FROM `match` m2
WHERE m2.round_id = @round_id AND
      m2.datetime < NOW() AND m2.status IN (1, 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

The comparison can never return less than 0 and since you want to return true if I understood you correctly no comparison is needed and also I don't see the need for SUM so I changed the query to

```
SELECT (m2.datetime < NOW() AND m2.status IN (1, 2)) AS result 
FROM `match` m2 WHERE m2.round_id = @round_id
```

Comment: your query return a list of 0

Comment: @zparo I got 1 for the last row and 0 for the others when running the query against your sample data but I skipped the WHERE clause because I don’t understand what `round_id` is.